Unable to build native image with GraalVM for Spring Boot 2.7.14
The jar was running successfully and image was also generated successfully with mvn -Pnative clean package. After generating the image, I try to run using ./native-image-name.
I get the following error

main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.14 version and GraalVM 17.
How to incorporate the versions and require dependencies to create and run a native build?

Please provide a [mre] and the full exception, not just a truncated part.
